# Google chrome opening to black screen Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, cpu-usage

Using google chrome version 41, downloaded it yesterday.  Now when I click the icon in the task bar it opens to a black screen.  Moving the cursor to the top I get a line that shows a red X and allows me to close, or I can click the google icon at the bottom, only thing there with black screen, and it will open to my preferred home page.  This thing is also using above 90% of my CPU and slowing live streaming to 1/3 of what it was before the new install.  I have deleted all extensions, cleared browser, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Version 41 is the latest **development** version. You should be running the latest **stable** version, which is 39.

[image]

Update: Latest stable version is now 40.

Source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history

Answer (score 0):

click on the three lines in upper right column
choose "relaunch chrome in **** and don't choose "windows 8"
This is the last item before exit

Comment: This is a duplicate of Stan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Download the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) and scan the PC. It will probably find some adware. Remove the adware, clear the browser cache, and reboot. This was the only thing that worked for me after I tried everyone else's suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. My solution:  to open to the web browser, right click on the Chrome icon in your bottom tray and select any webpage you find there.  Once the webpage is open, left click on the little 3-horizontal-line icon in the upper rt corner of the page just under the red X.  Then select "open Chrome in desktop mode" (or something to that effect).  This puts everything back to normal, as it was running in the "Open Chrome in Windows 8 mode".  Hope this helps someone.  Stan